# Error with Intel C++ compiler: identifier "_Compare" is undefined

Tags: c++, c++11, intel, icc

I am able to compile the following a std=c++11 required code with g++ using the following command:

`g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -Wl,-rpath,/share/apps/gcc/6.3.0/lib64`

the code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
int main() {
  typedef std::unique_ptr<int> intPointer;
  intPointer p(new int(10));
  std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> m;
  m.insert(std::make_pair(5, std::move(p)));
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start < std::chrono::seconds(2))
  {
      std::thread t;
  }
}
```

The very same command(probably I don't know the correct one) wont work for intel compiler:

```
icpc test.cpp -std=c++11 -Wl,-rpath,/share/apps/intel/2016.1.056/vtune_amplifier_xe_2016.1.1.434111/target/linux64/lib64
```

The error is:

```
In file included from /share/apps/gcc/6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/map(60),
             from test.cpp(2):
/share/apps/gcc/6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_tree.h(1437): 
error: identifier "_Compare" is undefined
     && is_nothrow_move_assignable<_Compare>::value)
                                   ^

In file included from /share/apps/gcc/6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/map(60),
             from test.cpp(2):
/share/apps/gcc/6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_tree.h(1778): 
error: identifier "_Compare" is undefined
  _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT_IF(__is_nothrow_swappable<_Compare>::value)
  ^
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I fix this.

Comment: Is it normal that your Intel compiler is using GCC headers? I have a feeling that's not going to work. Maybe you should use the Intel equivalent of same.

Comment: Well, the Piece of code is not written by me. It is part of a test for compiling a bigger software. If this code does not return an error, it let me compile. So changing the code is not what I can do. that is solid and given.

Comment: You say that and yet your compiler disagrees. Each vendor has their own implementation of the Standard Library and you can't just arbitrarily mix and match headers with compilers.

Comment: @tadman Intel says that to be able to use full functionality of c++11 I need to have gcc-4.8 or later, so they should be connected somehow:
*1: * Full C++11 support requires gcc 4.8 environment or newer on Linux*
[link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler)

Comment: So why not follow their advice and *use* the GCC compiler?

Comment: that advice was for 2014, you think it still applies? that will be bad news then

Comment: What I think is a bad idea is forcing one compiler to use another's internal headers. If you need to use GCC, if GCC works, then use GCC. If you need to support Intel's compiler, use Intel's compiler's headers.

Comment: `_Compare` is one of the template parameters of the `_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>` defined in that file, so surely it is defined. A suspicion is that the Intel compiler perhaps doesn't know about `is_nothrow_move_assignable` which is kind of recently added to the type_traits. A bug report might be in order.

Comment: @tadman It's perfectly normal. ICC piggybacks on the platform compiler's standard library implementation (GCC's for Linux, MSVC's for Windows). It doesn't come with its own standard library implementation.

Comment: @BoPersson This is helpful enough. Thank you very much. Please provide an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I checked with Intel agents and it turned out that Intel 16 do not support gcc6.3, the support comes in Intel 17.

Answer (score 3):

*From the comments above:*

`_Compare` is one of the template parameters of the `_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>` defined in that file, so surely it is defined.

A more likely reason is that the Intel compiler perhaps doesn't know about `is_nothrow_move_assignable` which is kind of recently added to the type_traits.

Answer (score 3):

I had a user with a similar c++ difficulty using gcc-6.3.0 headers and the Intel 16.1.150 compiler. I opted for the compiler bug theory, tried with the Intel 17 compiler and things worked.
-doug